# How to dynamically build up a query in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to dynamically build up my where clause for my linq query.

I have a search option which can search for name, sex and location. How can I dynamically build up my linq query so that if only name is entered I get something like:

```
profiles.where(function(x) x.name = <<nameValue>>)
```

but when the name is entered and the location I would get something like:

```
profiles.where(function(x) x.name = <<nameValue>> AND x.location = <<locationValue>>)
```

kind regards

Comment: Are you using Dynamic Linq? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
Dim pred = PredicateBuilder.True(Of Profile)()
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameValue) Then
    pred = pred.And(Function(x) x.name = nameValue)
End If
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(locationValue) Then
    pred = pred.And(Function(x) x.location = locationValue)
End If

Dim query = profiles.Where(pred)
```

(Note: this solution assumes `profiles` is an `IQueryable<Profile>`, e.g. an Entity Framework `DbSet` or `ObjectSet`; if it's just a normal collection, use `profiles.AsQueryable()` instead of `profiles`)

Answer (score 1):

If your conditions are always `AND`ed, and never `OR`ed you can build your query one step at the time:

```
Dim query = profiles.AsQueryable()

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameValue) Then
    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.name = nameValue)
End If

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(locationValue) Then
    query = query .Where(Function(x) x.location = locationValue)
End If

Return query.ToList()
```

LINQ queries execution is deferred so it's not executed until result are necessary or you explicitly ask it to execute, e.g. calling `ToList()` method.